# How to change wordpress query_posts by clicking a link?

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have posts queried by a taxonomy, and I'd like to a have an option available for the front-end user to re-order the posts. Is this clear? Example: 20 movies ordered by date (when the movie was premiered) and the user clicks a link to order the movies DESC or ASC by date.

What's the best way to achieve this? Should I use ajax or something to change the query_posts? I'm a bit (?) lost!

I've tried using ?order=ASC&orderby=Data after the url in links, but it only seems to work on "regular" loop.

Thanks, Dani.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about passing the arguments by GET as you suggest, and then manually composing your custom query with query_posts or whatever you are using?

The link to change order:

```
<a href="?order=DESC&orderby=Data">Data, descencing</a>
```

And the PHP:

```
if( !empty($_GET['order']) ) $order=$_GET['order'];
else $order='DESC'; // default

if( !empty($_GET['orderby']) ) $orderby=$_GET['orderby'];
else $orderby = 'Data'; // default

query_posts('orderby='.$orderby.'&order='.$order);
```

It would probably be smoother for most users to do it with AJAX so the page doesn't reload, but it has its own drawbacks (accessibility wise) and you would need a bit more work to implement it.

Comment: Just what I was after. Thank you!!